# How to code EEPROM with potentiometer in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, robotics, eeprom, servo

I have A code I got from a site. I've been trying to add EEPROM in that code but I can't get it right. I tried adding EEPROM.write and EEPROm.read I also add another servo

Can someone help me with it, **Adding EEPROM in the code?** Thank you in advance :)

here's the code (Simple Robotic arm with play and record function):

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

const int PinButton1 = 2;  // pin 2   
const int PinButton2 = 3;  // pin 3
int mode = 1;     // case 1 program robot arm. case 2 replay positions 
int bounce = 0;
volatile int buttonPress = 0;
unsigned long lastButtonPressTime = 0;
volatile unsigned long bounceTime = 0;
Servo Arm0Servo;      //servo objects
Servo Arm1Servo;      // Ihave renumbered servos 26 1 2017
Servo Arm2Servo;
Servo Arm3Servo;
Servo Arm4Servo;
int pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos0;
int PosArm[5] ;       // array 
int ArmPos[100][5];   // array to hold arm positions up to 100
int PosCount = 0;     //  to count number of positions increased when button     pressed
int PosCountMax = 0;  //  number of positions recorded when double button push initiates replay mode
int PosReached = 0;   // used to check that arm has moved from one recorded position to next position
int addr = 0;
boolean recorded = false;

void setup() {  
     for(int i = 0; i <100 ; i++ ){
     for(int p = 0; p <5 ; p++ ){
         ArmPos[i][p] = -1;
     }
 }
pinMode(PinButton1 , OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(PinButton1 ,LOW);
pinMode(PinButton2, INPUT_PULLUP);
//  I have made a small change here due to problem using some Arduinos
//attachInterrupt( digitalPinToInterrupt(PinButton2),ButtonPress , LOW );
// digitalPinToInterrupt(PinButton2) may not be defined!
attachInterrupt( 1,ButtonPress , LOW );   // interupt to capture button presses

// attach servos to relervent pins on arduino nano
Arm0Servo.attach(12); // grip    90 to 180 open    limits of servo movement
Arm1Servo.attach(11); // elbow      to 130 up
Arm2Servo.attach(10); // shoulder   10 to 50 down
Arm3Servo.attach(9);  // turn    0  to 180 right 
Arm4Servo.attach(8);  // turn    0  to 180 right
}

void loop() {
  switch(mode){
    case 1 :  //  program robot arm. 1 press to remember position. 2 presses to progress next case 2 replay mode
              // analogRead(pin) that reads poteniometers on training arm
    PosArm[0] = map(analogRead(0),480,1024,180,10); // map (480,1024 value from potentiometer to 180,90 value sent to servo)
    EEPROM.write(addr, PosArm[0]);
    addr++;
    PosArm[1] = map(analogRead(1),480,1024,180,10);
    EEPROM.write(addr, PosArm[1]);
    addr++;
    PosArm[2] = map(analogRead(2),480,1024,180,10);
    EEPROM.write(addr, PosArm[2]);
    addr++;
    PosArm[3] = map(analogRead(3),480,1024,180,10);
    EEPROM.write(addr, PosArm[3]);
    addr++;
    PosArm[4] = map(analogRead(4),480,1024,180,10);
    EEPROM.write(addr, PosArm[4]);
             addr++;
    MoveArm();                          // call method  
    if(buttonPress == 1){               // flag set by interupt when button is pressed          
         buttonPress = 0;               // reset flag 
         if( millis() > (lastButtonPressTime + 1000)){    // only one button press in one secound
             // record  position of arm PosArm to array[100][] of armpositions        
             ArmPos[PosCount][0] = PosArm[0];

             ArmPos[PosCount][1] = PosArm[1];

             ArmPos[PosCount][2] = PosArm[2];

             ArmPos[PosCount][3] = PosArm[3];

             ArmPos[PosCount][4] = PosArm[4];


             if (addr == 512) {
               EEPROM.write(addr, 255);
               break;
             }

             if( PosCount < 100) {      // stop recording if over 100 positions recorded (memory limitations)
                 PosCount++;         
             }
         }else{                         //  more than one button press
             mode = 2;                  // go to next phase
             PosCountMax  = PosCount;   // set number of arm positions recorded
             PosCount = 0;              // reset count ready to read  arm position array from begining 
         }
    lastButtonPressTime = millis();              
    }
  break;
case 2 :        // read arm position array
    PosReached = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <5 ; i++ ){   //adjust servo positions   
        // we move the servos in small steps and the delay(20)  makes arm motion smooth and slow
        if( PosArm[i] > ArmPos[PosCount][i]) PosArm[i] = PosArm[i] - 1;  // if actual position is greater than requird position reduce position by 1
        if( PosArm[i] < ArmPos[PosCount][i]) PosArm[i] = PosArm[i] + 1;  // if actual position is less than required position value increase position valuue by 1
        if( PosArm[i] == ArmPos[PosCount][i]) PosReached++;              // check if servo  has reached required position/angle
    }

    if(PosReached == 5) PosCount++;        // if all 4 servos have reached position  then increase array index (PosCount)to next position in array
    if(PosCount == PosCountMax) PosCount = 0;   //  if end of array reached reset index to 0 and repeat.
    Play();   // physically move arm to updated position, this is broken into small steps
    delay(5);   // pause between moves so over all motion is slowed down
  break;
default :
  break;
  }    
}

void MoveArm() {   // write arm position data to servos
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
  if (PosArm[i] < 5) PosArm[i] = 5;  // limit servo movement to prevent hitting end stops
  if (PosArm[i] > 175) PosArm[i] = 175;  // servo.write limited 5 - 175  
  }
  Arm0Servo.write(PosArm[0]);
  Arm1Servo.write(PosArm[1]);
  Arm2Servo.write(PosArm[2]);
  Arm3Servo.write(PosArm[3]);
  Arm4Servo.write(PosArm[4]);
  Play();
  delay(5);
}
void Play() {   // write arm position data to servos
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
  if (PosArm[i] < 5) PosArm[i] = 5;  // limit servo movement to prevent hitting end stops
  if (PosArm[i] > 175) PosArm[i] = 175;  // servo.write limited 5 - 175  
  }

  if (addr == 0) {
  PosArm[0] = EEPROM.read(addr);
  pos0 = EEPROM.read(addr+5);
  addr++;

  PosArm[1] = EEPROM.read(addr);
  pos1 = EEPROM.read(addr+5);
  addr++;

  PosArm[2] = EEPROM.read(addr);
  pos2 = EEPROM.read(addr+5);
  addr++;

  PosArm[3] = EEPROM.read(addr);
  pos3 = EEPROM.read(addr+5);
  addr++;

  PosArm[4] = EEPROM.read(addr);
  pos4 = EEPROM.read(addr+5);
  addr++;

  }

  }
   void ButtonPress(){   //  interupt to capture button press
   if(micros() > (bounceTime + 3000)){ // debounce timer 
    bounceTime = micros();          // ingnore interupts due to button bounce
    buttonPress = 1;     // flag for button pressed
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean, "add EEPROM" ?  Your program can write to it and/or read from it, what do you want to do and what did you try so far ?

Comment: The program works well, it write and read, but I want to save the write data in the EEPROM permanently. I tried EEPROM. write and EEPROM.read, it still works but it can't read the write data anymore. Thank You :)

Comment: So where is your code that does this ?

Comment: I will edit the posted code above.

Comment: done editing it.

Comment: Please reduce your code sample! This is not the review center for your work! If you have a problem like writing to eeprom, please reduce your code exactly to that!

Answer (score 1):

The code that you posted will never attempt to read data from the EEPROM due to the following problem:

When your microcontroller is started, the variable `mode` is set to 1. If you look carefully at the `loop` function you can see that your code will enter the `case 1` branch at least once where it basically writes data to the EEPROM and - more importantly - will set `addr` to a value other than 0, due to the `addr++` instructions (unless you run the code so long that you encounter an integer overflow).

The only place where you attempt to read from the EEPROM is in the `Play` function. Due to the `if (addr == 0)` condition in this function you will never execute the `EEPROM.read` instructions as `addr` will not be 0 as explained above.

Comment: Johannes is right. Furthermore, this sketch will write to the EEPROM 1000+ times a second unless it enters mode 2 or 3. That will give your EEPROM a lifetime of a little under 2 hours to reach a cell cycle of 100000 as per ATMEL is the lifespan. So you would really want to redo your handling of EEPROM. And your Arduino might already have a dead EEPROM.